# How to build Yeoman Backbone without uglifying?

Tags: backbone.js, yeoman, gruntjs

I'm using Yeoman 1.0 and the latest version of the [Backbone generator](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone) and everything I've written is working in development, however when I `$ grunt build` the resulting `/dist` is throwing the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: Backbone is not defined
```

Unfortunately, since the js has been minified, trying to debug is almost pointless. Is there a way to "build" without the minification? I've tried playing around with settings in the [gruntfile](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js) but can't seem to find the right options for the right task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you share your GruntFile.js to check the configurations?

By the way, you can omit the minification, don't use uglify or whatever task you have been running so, give it a try to `grunt-contrib-copy` task which copies the files to designated folder (prod/dist).

https://github.com/gruntjs/grunt-contrib-copy

```
  // Configuration goes here
  grunt.initConfig({

    // Configure the copy task to move files from the development to production folders
    copy: {
      target: {
        files: {
          'prod/': ['dev/**']
        }
      }
    },
  });
```

Comment: I linked the [gruntfile](https://github.com/yeoman/generator-backbone/blob/master/app/templates/Gruntfile.js) in the question. I'm just having trouble isolating which task in there is doing the minification, since Yeoman generators typically have quite complex gruntfiles. Adding a copy command won't help since I need to preserve all of the other tasks to isolate the problem with my js.

Comment: I missed the attached GruntFile anyway 'Uglify' is doing the minification at line no. 191 ,check the 'files' key, you can change the configuration as per your need.

'Uglify' has been added as task at line no. 362.

Comment: Yup, I just realized that disabling that line was in fact doing the job, however my browser had already cached the minified version :( so I thought there was another problem.

Comment: Cool, you nailed down the issue :)